# how to split a column in dataframe of bit vectors into separate columns in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a column of strings in form of a 0,1 vector.
For example, the first row would like this:

```
 1st.row <- "01100101111101011101101"
```

I would like to convert this string into binary entries in multiple columns so as the first row would be

```
 1st.row.split <- c(0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1)
```

The binary vector should split among 23 columns, in this case, which is the number of elements in the string vector. All rows have same number of elements.
Thanks.

Comment: `unlist(strsplit(row, ""))`?

Answer (score 1):

```
row1 <- "01100101111101011101101"
rowsplt<- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(row1,"")))
```

Comment: Fantastic! What if there was a table containing multiple rows like this, and I wanted to apply this to all rows? e.g.

    row1 01100101111101011101101
    row2 0110010100010001000010
    row3 0000001000010100100010

(Sorry, trying to format this accurately to put this into a chunk of code but being unsuccessful)

Comment: @rodduart what is your table? is it a dataframe?

Comment: It is a dataframe, yes! (Sorry, you were too fast, I am still trying to find the correct way of formatting my example input data in my comment above haha)

Comment: @rodduart well just do `read.table(text = gsub('(.)','\\1 ',data$your_col),fill=TRUE)`